# How to share code from jupyter notebook to server installed with python3?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have written python code in jupyter notebook, And now I need to keep or share the same in server installed with python3.

So that other person with jupyter notebook can connect to this server and get the code and run on their system.

Please suggest me how to do it or any blogs or tutorial related to it.

Thank you.

Comment: The "best" way to share a Jupyter notebook is to simply to place it on GitHub (and view it directly) or some other public link and use the Jupyter Notebook Viewer or use this https://towardsdatascience.com/tools-for-sharing-jupyter-notebooks-online-28c8d4ff821c

Answer (score 0):

I had to browse throughly.
Here I got the solution.
https://ljvmiranda921.github.io/notebook/2018/01/31/running-a-jupyter-notebook/